# Accessing JSON file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, get

I recently created a new Anguar App and wanted to store some data in a JSON file. I was wondering 1) where best to store the .json file within the app and 2) how to access said file.

I am currently getting the following error in my Chrome console:
GET http://localhost:8000/travelMap/stateData.json 404 (Not Found)

This is a simple app, but I am newer to Angular/Javascript and want to make sure this follows best practices.

Thank you!

My folder structure is as follows:
[I would like to access the json in the travelMapCtrl and I've stored the json file in the same folder as this controller (travelMap) for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYYRu.png)

This is the JS where I am attempting to access the json:

```js
$http.get('stateData.json').then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: try this http://localhost:8000/components/travelMap/stateData.json ur file is in component folder..

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I actually updated the path to /components/travelMap/stateData.json and that worked. So simple. Thanks for the help!

Comment: sure np ^^ feel free to ping me for any angularjs related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http service is unable to locate the file because the argument that you pass to $http.get() is the path relative to the root of the app (not relative to where the controller is).

You can put your JSON files in a data folder and pass the relative path to the root app folder. For instance, if your root app is in "app" folder, then you can create a "data" folder inside the "app" folder and insert your stateData.json file in it. Then your API call would be: `$http.get("/data/stateData.json")`

Your app structure would be:

```
LauraApp/app/app.js
LauraApp/app/data/stateData.json
```